# show a dialog before closing the program in Qt

Tags: c++, qt

I want to show the dialog before closing the program in Qt whether the user wants to cancel or save the program, i.e. by clicking on cancel the user has chance to return to program with uncleaned state, like windows paint, or notepad in which the aware dialog before closing appear alerting the users?
by the way I use Qt

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If your application uses ***QMainWindow***, overload the `closeEvent()` to show the dialog and only call `QMainWindow::closeEvent` if the user clicked **ok** in your dialog.

If your application uses a ***QDialog***, overload the `accept()` slot and only call `QDialog::accept` if the user clicked **ok** in your dialog.

Comment: I'm not sure what was in Qt4, but in Qt5, just not calling `QMainWindow::closeEvent()` is not enough to prevent window from closing: you need to call `event->ignore()` additionally, as explained here: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#closeEvent

Answer (score 7):

you can use the solution described here: [https://web.archive.org/web/20170716164107/http://www.codeprogress.com/cpp/libraries/qt/HandlingQCloseEvent.php](http://www.codeprogress.com/cpp/libraries/qt/HandlingQCloseEvent.php)

you can simply override closeEvent function by:

```
#include <QCloseEvent>
#include <QMessageBox>
void MainWindow::closeEvent(QCloseEvent *event)  // show prompt when user wants to close app
{
    event->ignore();
    if (QMessageBox::Yes == QMessageBox::question(this, "Close Confirmation", "Exit?", QMessageBox::Yes | QMessageBox::No))
    {
        event->accept();
    }

}
```