# How to trigger a method after closing a dialog box

Tags: c++, qt, callback, dialog, delegates

I made a simple tool application. There is a settings button that opens a settings dialog window. There is a save button that saves the settings and closes the window. What i want is how to make the main window execute a particular function when the dialog is closed.

I get the closeEvent in settingsdialog to fire but not sure how to call a method on mainwindow from closeevent.

EDIT: I manage to override closeEvent, but the thing im not sure is how to fire a method in the Mainwindow from SettingDialog. I tried this:

```
void SettingsDialog::closeEvent(QCloseEvent *event) {

    qDebug() << "CloseEvent Called";
    QTimer::singleShot(250, this, &MainWindow::SettingsSaved);

}
```

It give error:

> error: no matching function for call to 'QTimer::singleShot(int,
>   SettingsDialog*, void (MainWindow::*)())'
>        QTimer::singleShot(250, this, &MainWindow::SettingsSaved);
>                                                                ^

Comment: You can use a single shot timer triggered in an overloaded `closeEvent()`

Comment: Override the `closeEvent()` of your dialog widget and get it to emit a signal on close which is then handled by the main window.

Comment: Can u give example code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [show a dialog before closing the program in Qt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13129380/show-a-dialog-before-closing-the-program-in-qt)

Comment: Edited my question pls take a look.

Comment: If your function exists on `MainWindow` class, then give a pointer to main window instead of `this`, also if you want to run a function on close and keep the window visible until the end of the function, use `event->ignore();` to prevent the close of window while something stills running or are waiting to run, then call `close` method of `QWidget` when you’re ready to close the window, and do not call `event->ignore();` this time.

Comment: @AntonioDias I changed this to &MainWindow, but error: expected primary-expression before ',' token
     QTimer::singleShot(250, &MainWindow, &MainWindow::SettingsSaved);

Comment: SettingsSaved is a public slot in MainWindow fyi.

Comment: @GeneCode - `this` is of type `SettingsDialog` not of type `MainWindow`.

Comment: @dtech ya I already changed it to &MainWindow but still error.

Comment: You need `QTimer::singleShot(250, mainwindowPtr, &MainWindow::SettingsSaved);` `&SomeClass` doesn't give you a pointer to an actual object. You may have to pass that pointer when you create the dialog. Or if you parented the dialog to the main window, you can `qobject_cast` the `parent()` of the dialog to get the main window pointer.

Comment: Where do I get mainwindowPtr?

Comment: closeEvent not working on my case. singleshot never called inside closeEvent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Addressing the updated question:

Pass the main window pointer as a parent when you create the dialog:

```
new SettingsDialog(this);
```

assuming you are creating it from within the main window. Now you have a pointer to the main window inside the dialog, although it will show up as a `QWidget *`.

Cast the parent to the appropriate type:

```
MainWindow * mainptr = qobject_cast<MainWindow *>(parent());
```

And you don't really even need to use the timer for the kind of thing you are trying to achieve, you can simply:

`if (mainptr) mainptr->SettingsSaved();`

So, in the end, something like this:

```
void SettingsDialog::closeEvent(QCloseEvent *event) {
   if (settingsAreAllOK) {
     MainWindow * mainptr = qobject_cast<MainWindow *>(parent());
     if (mainptr) mainptr->SettingsSaved();
     event->accept();
   } else event->ignore();
}
```